# Books or references on multidimensional matrix operations

Tags: reference-request, matrices, matrix-theory

Have the 2D matrix operations been generalized to n-dimensional matrices?

Are there any books that define various operations on multidimensional matrix? I'd like to see operations such as multidimensional matrix multiplication, multidimensional matrix transpose, multidimensional matrix inversion.

I got only this [reference](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2010/WCE2010_pp1824-1828.pdf) on the net.

Comment: Don't you mean tensors ?

Comment: No. I wonder if there could be any differences between tensors and multidimensional matrices.

Comment: Multidimensional matrices are known as tensors, and working with them is known as multilinear algebra. If you dig around, you can find expositions of this.

Comment: @Yang thank you. I guess, the term multidimensional matrix is not used in mainstream literature. That was the main reason for my confusion.

Comment: I guess they use n-dimensional matrices in (n+1)-dimensional worlds

Answer (score 2):

There are two old books, authored by N.P. Sokolov, and available in Russian only:

"Spatial matrices and their applications", Gos. Izdat. Fiz.-Mat. Lit., Moscow, 1960 [[MR: 0130256](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=130256)] and "Introduction to the theory of multidimensional matrices", Naukova Dumka, Kiev, 1972 [MR: 0352115]. At least the first of these books is available on the web.

From the MR review of the first book:

> Such arrays were first considered by Cayley [Trans. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 8 (1842/49), 75–88; pp. 85–88] and have since been the subject of numerous investigations. Of the considerable literature that has grown up in this field, we may mention a long series of papers by M. Lecat published between 1910 and 1929 and also, in more recent years, the work of R. Oldenburger.

I guess this topic is out of fashion now.

Comment: What's in these books that's different from what's known about tensors?

Comment: @Deane Yang: Frankly, I do not know, I haven't looked thoroughly. I think the difference is in the language, e.g. matrices (as rectangular arrays of numbers) vs. linear maps.